# Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1

Tags: android

There is no problem while running the app in mobile as well as emulator. But I am getting the following error while generating signed APK

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Module Gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 3
    versionName "2.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

implementation 'com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

implementation 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'

implementation 'io.apptik.widget:multislider:1.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
}


configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project Gradle is :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.+'


    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You need to check your dependency with the following command: ./gradlew app: dependencies
Maybe one of your libraries contains support library and you need to exclude it from that particular library

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
```

And don't forget to add `multiDexEnabled true`.